# Finding MLE of for exponential with $\log(\mu)=\alpha$, $\mu=1/\theta$, transformation

Tags: maximum-likelihood

I have some troubles with the following.

I'm trying to find a MLE for $\alpha$, when $X_i \text{~} Exp(\theta)$,$\mu=1/\theta$ and $\log(\mu)=\alpha$. Also $n=30$.

i.e.

$\mu=e^{\alpha}=1/\theta$

$\implies \log(\mu)=\log(1)-\log(\theta)=\alpha$
$\implies \log(\theta)=-\alpha$
$\implies \theta=e^{- \alpha}$

where $\mu$ is the mean.

What I've then got is:

$L(\alpha)=\prod_{i=1}^n [e^{-\alpha} e^{-e^{-\alpha} x_i }]$
$=[e^{-n\alpha} e^{-e^{-\alpha} \sum{x_i} }]$

$l(\alpha)=\log([e^{-n\alpha} e^{-e^{-\alpha} \sum{x_i} }])$
$=-n \alpha -e^{-\alpha} \sum{x_i}$

$\frac{\partial l(\alpha)}{\partial \alpha}=-n-\sum{x_i}\frac{\partial e^{u} }{\partial u}\frac{- \alpha}{\partial \alpha}$
$=-n+e^{- \alpha}\sum{x_i}$

$V(\alpha)=-n+e^{- \alpha}\sum{x_i}$
and then I've been given the Jacobian:
$J(\alpha)=n$

Are my equations correct?

Then I want to use Newton's method:

$$\alpha^{(k+1)}=\alpha^{(k)}-\frac{V(\alpha^{(k)})}{J(\alpha^{(k)})}$$

But using

$V(\alpha)=-n+e^{- \alpha}\sum{x_i}$ does not converge, whereas using

$V(\alpha)=-n+e^{\alpha}\sum{x_i}$

gives the opposite sign:

[image]

since by gammer's answer the answer should be $\hat{\alpha}=-0.2514...$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X_1, ..., X_n \sim {\rm exponential}(\theta)$ then [the MLE for $\theta$ is $1/\overline{X}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Maximum_likelihood), where $\overline{X} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i$.

By [the functional invariance property of MLEs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation#Functional_invariance) the MLE of $\alpha = \log(1/\theta)$ is therefore $\hat{\alpha} = \log(\overline{X})$.

Comment: But can I not approximate the MLE like I'm doing it? Rather, would I need to perform Newton on $\theta$ and then transform that to $\alpha$? Rather than computing in $\alpha$ directly?

Comment: I was giving the analytic solution to your question. Of course you can compute it numerically if you re-parameterize in terms of $\alpha$. Your equation for the likelihood looks right. I suspect you've made an error in calculating the derivative. You'll know you did it right if the answer you get equals $\log(\overline{X})$...

Comment: There's your problem. You're presumably trying to find roots of the score function. In that case, the steps in Newton-Raphson are supposed to be $f'(\alpha_k)/f''(\alpha_k)$. In place of $f'(\alpha_k)$ in your steps you have $f(\alpha_k)$, and where $f''(\alpha_k)$ should be you have $n$, neither of which are right.

Comment: I'm using $\hat{\theta}^{(k+1)}=\hat{\theta}^{(k)}-\mathbb{H}^{-1}(\hat{\theta}^{(k)})V(\hat{\theta}^{(k)})$ version of Newton.

Comment: Just ditch the numerical approximation and compute $\log(\overline{X})$. And it's up to you whether or not you want to delete the question. I'll leave the answer because it's right.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56435/discussion-between-mavavilj-and-gammer).